# TableRow divisão de linhas - Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Estava olhando sobre TableRow e desenvolvendo uma app de teste com este modelo de layout e surgiu uma dúvida.
Tenho uma Tabela com 1 Linha e duas colunas, cuja situação é apresentada na figura abaixo. Porém na coluna 2 ela não está totalmente preenchida por conteúdo, é possível eu "dividir" esta coluna como esta e inserir outro textView abaixo deste que ela ja possui para completar o conteúdo? Pois ai eu inseriria o valor da temperatura abaixo da escrita "Temperatura"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TableRow deve ser usado dentro de TableLayout, caso não seja se comporta como um Linearlayout horizontal.

Sendo TableRow um layout(extends LinearLayout) pode conter qualquer view, incluindo outro tipo de layout.

Assim, para conseguir ter os dois TextView um por debaixo do outro, coloque-os dentro de um LinearLayout com orientação vertical:

```
...
    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow>
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/ic_weathernow"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Temperatura"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="28º"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
...
```

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado! Para esta solução deu certo! Agora estou inserindo uma table row com 2 colunas e outra tablerow com 4 colunas sendo 2 imageview e 2 textview (alternadas) e está aparecendo somente uma imageview e uma textview, sabe me dizer o que pode ser?

Comment: Pode ser por várias razões. O melhor é dar esta pergunta como [resolvida](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e fazer outra.